# Bypass entry when object not desired on Wizard

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, pagereference

I have a case entry wizard, duped and revised from the Visualforce in Practice workbook.
My second page asks the users if they want to add Case Team Members. 
If they put a user in the name box, they can add a user, and this works fine. 
But I can't seem to get them to be able to bypass this if they don't want to add anyone. It sees the name as required.
I tried to skip the insert Case Team Member section of the code on my "Complete Entry" button but it doesn't seem to matter. How can I get it to navigate to the new Case without entering info. Please assist! thanks.

Extension:

```
public class CasewithCaseTeamExtension {

private ApexPages.StandardController sc;

public CaseTeamMember CTM {get; set;}
public List<CaseTeamMember> CTMS {get; set;}

public String selectedCaseTeamMember {get; set;}   

public string Username {
        get {
            return [
                    select Name
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                ].Name;
        }
        set;

}   

public CasewithCaseTeamExtension (ApexPages.StandardController StandardController) {

    //Store a reference to the standard controller
    sc = standardController;

    //create a new sprint instance to collect user input
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    //create a new list to store the sprints added by the user
    CTMS = new List<CaseTeamMember>();



}    


public PageReference ToPage2() {

    if(ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetURL().ToLowerCase().StartsWith('/apex/CaseCreateCTM1')){

        //Save code will go here



    }
    sc.save();
    return Page.CaseCreateCTM2;

}    
public PageReference SaveCTM() {

    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();
    CaseTeamRole CTRole = [select id from CaseTeamRole where name =:'Support'];
    CTM.ParentId = Case1.Id;
    CTM.TeamRoleId = CTRole.Id;
    insert CTM;

    CTMS.Add(CTM);
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    return null;

}  

public PageReference SaveAndFinish() {

    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();
    CaseTeamRole CTRole = [select id from CaseTeamRole where name =:'KCG'];
    CTM.ParentId = Case1.Id;
    CTM.TeamRoleId = CTRole.Id;


    CTMS.Add(CTM);
    CTM = new CaseTeamMember();

    PageReference redirecturl = new PageReference('/'+Case1.id);
    return redirecturl;

}    
public PageReference FinishEntry() {
    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();


    PageReference redirecturl = new PageReference('/'+Case1.id);
    return redirecturl;

}


}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CasewithCaseTeamExtension" >

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Add Interested Parties to the Case Team Members List Here">
            Case Team Members will be included in email notifications about the Case.   
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                     <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveCTM}" value="Add Person to Case" />
                   <apex:commandButton action="{!FinishEntry}" value="Complete Case Entry" />

                </apex:pageBlockButtons>   
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
              <apex:inputField value="{!ctm.MemberId}" label="Name" />

                    </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
             <apex:pageBlock title="Added">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CTMS}" var="s">
                    <apex:column value="{!s.MemberId}"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I want it to go to the new Case page when the User clicks the Complete Case Entry button, which calls FinishEntry, shown again right below, but I get the "You must enter a value" error. Thanks!

```
public PageReference FinishEntry() {
    Case Case1 = (Case)sc.GetRecord();


    PageReference redirecturl = new PageReference('/'+Case1.id);
    return redirecturl;

}
```

[image]

Comment: can you try setting immediate = true on the complete case entry command button, I believe it skips all the validations. Not too sure abt the required field criteria, give it a try!!! Refer ; https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-immediate-attribute-on-commandlinks-and-commandbuttons.html

Comment: This worked, thanks. You want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting immediate = true on the complete case entry command button, I believe it skips all the validations.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-immediate-attribute-on-commandlinks-and-commandbuttons.html